# C# make background image fit the screen?

Tags: c#, winforms, background, resize

I decided to add a background image to my winforms application and I wonder how I can make the background always fit with the screen? (auto-stretch it).

I have a form where users can resize it and choose their own window size, but I want the background to always fill the application. I have a huge background wallpaper, about 2000x1500 in resolution, if the user resize the form window to about 500x500 it will only show a small part of the wallpaper, how can I make it show the full wallpaper but in a smaller resolution?

I haven't found anything about this and I have no idea where to even start.
Could anyone help me?

Comment: Change the BackgroundImageLayout property.  Hard to miss, it is right underneath BacgroundImage in the Properties window.

Answer (score 9):

Just set the forms `BackgroundImageLayout` to `Stretch`.

This will probably cause flickering, to prevent this you can (in the ctor):

```
this.SetStyle(
    ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
    ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer,
    true);
```

Answer (score 4):

Set the [BackgroundImageLayout()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backgroundimagelayout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the Form to either "Stretch" or "Zoom".

Answer (score -1):

```
private void MDIParent1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\Downloads\\2137969.png");
        this.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Stretch;
    }
```

Comment: provide an explanation with your answer.